# Can't Parse a double from user input Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to learn and create a basic sales tax app (inputs from item price and tax). In order to do this, I need to use a float or double for the decimals. I am very new to kotlin and don't know much, so I do not understand how I can get my num1 to parseDouble, I can clearly do it with the Integer data type with no errors. I've also tried toDouble which is giving me errors. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```kotlin
val calcButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.calcButton)
calcButton.setOnClickListener {
   var textPrice: EditText = findViewById(R.id.textPrice)
   var textTax:   EditText = findViewById(R.id.textTax)
   var textTotal: EditText = findViewById(R.id.textTotal)

   // error here: "Unresolved reference: parseDouble"
   var num1 = Double.parseDouble(textTax.getText().toString());
   // "parseInt" is working, however
   var num2 = Integer.parseInt(textTax.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
textTax.getText().toString().toDouble();
```

The reason you can't use `Double.parseDouble` is because [`Double`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-double/) in kotlin is not exactly the same as [`Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) in Java, therefore, just calling `Double` will call kotlin's version, which doesn't have `parseDouble` static method.

If you want to use the `Double` from `java.lang`, you must specify the full package name:

```
java.lang.Double.parseDouble(textTax.getText().toString());
```

Or you can also do:

```
import java.lang.Double.*;
parseDouble(textTax.getText().toString());
```

I would suggest just sticking with Kotlin's versions, as they usually result in shorter code.

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly! I decided to try Kotlin today just cause i have java experience.